# turn 1st row into + 3 columns in file txt

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

[image]I have a txt file, which looks like this:

```
#A9999999999999              012021I                                   
0099999999    000000000099999999+000000000000000000-000000000000000000-  
0099999999    000000000099999999+000000000000000000-000000000000000000-  
0099999999    000000000099999999+000000000000000000-000000000000000000-  
0099999999    000000000099999999+000000000000000000-000000000000000000-
```

With the first row I want to create 3 more columns

```
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
```

This example would include 3 columns with the value of the first row, first column with these positions 1st Column (08-15) 2nd column (30-35), 3rd column position 36 with the data of the 1st row.

During the insertion of the first part of the file the tab has changed the structure a little for some browsers. So I put a photo of what the layout of the file looks like.

I am currently using Debian. The first few attempts I was trying with `cat` and `sed`. As I'm not familiar with the syntax I came to ask for some examples.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. I don't understand how you can get this output from your input. Where does the `012021` come from? Where does the `I` come from? Why is the first field now `9999999`? Also, what operating system are you using? We need to know what tools you will have available. But most importantly, we need to understand what you need and at the moment it is very unclear.

Comment: Also, show us what you tried and what happened when you tried it.  While some people here like teaching how to write scripts or enjoy the challenge of solving scripting puzzles, this site is not a free script-writing service.  You are far more likely to get a good answer if you show what you've already tried or explain where you're stuck.

Comment: In my browser it shows the correct tab. I put an image so that it can be easier to see. Searching the internet I found several examples of handling txt files. I need this because I'm downloading several txt files from Google Drive and saving to a directory. This first part was done in python, I used the drive API and auth. Now I need to treat these files to be able to import into postgres. I've already prepared this third stage which will be in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep every process in 1 execution block in CSV handling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683363/keep-every-process-in-1-execution-block-in-csv-handling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    pfx = substr($0,8,7) OFS substr($0,30,6) OFS substr($0,36,1)
    next
}
{
    gsub(/[+-]/,"& ")
    $1 = pfx OFS $1
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
```

Comment: It worked very well. How could I save the edited file with the same name as it has. The idea was to run on multiple files in 1 folder. thanks

Comment: With GNU awk `awk -i inplace 'script' *`,wIth other awks `tmp=$(mktemp); for f in *; do awk 'script' "$f" > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$f"; done`.

Comment: With 'awk -i inplace 'script' *' return "awk: not an option: -i" 

 Do i need to install some awk package?

Comment: As I mentioned you need to use GNU awk for that.