# change date format in csv

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following csv

```
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
```

I want to format the second column always adding day 01 as day

```
9999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
```

Comment: Why do you have only 2 lines of output from 4 lines of input?

Comment: It's unclear what the original date format is.  Also, your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/680911/493832) shows the same data on another format. Would it not be better to work with that rather than adding yet another post-processing step?

Comment: the original date format is MM / YYYY.

I want to add the DD as 01 for every month. Getting YYYY-MM-DD.

Yes, I'm actually doing it step-by-step because I couldn't put everything together in a single execution block

Comment: Why do you show the ***exact same***  input line four times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like in `awk` can do the work:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","} {a=substr($2,1,2);b=substr($2,3,4);$2=b"-"a"-01";print $0}' input_file
```

Be aware this will work with almost any `awk`. For Solaris use  `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or  `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` (see @EdMorton comment)

P.S. I assume in `012021` `01` is the month and `2021` is the year

Comment: What is GNU specific here? I don't see it. Your approach works with gawk, mawk and busybox awk in my tests.

Comment: @terdon, what I mean this will not work with standard Solaris `awk`, (with high probability) with AIX `awk`

Comment: OK, but why? I am afraid I don't understand what "change of input token/field" means. Do you mean the `-F`?

Comment: @terdon, no. Expression `$2=b"-"a"-01"` (assign value to input field) do not work on some `awk` implementations

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I didn't know that.

Comment: solaris awk as I learned from @EdMorton is a broken awk, so what you do will work in almost every awk implementations but probably not in that solaris broken awk, so it's not only a GNU awk specific. also please move setting `OFS` to the `BEGING{}` block instead of setting it for every input line or use `-v OFS=,`

Comment: @αғsнιη, you are right, the place of `OFS` is in `BEGIN` :)

Comment: @Romeo `$2=b"-"a"-01"` and everything else in your script will work in any awk, and by any awk I mean any except old, broken awk (which unfortunately is the default awk on Solaris) which can always be ignored in such statements because it's old and broken and must never be used and would have to be listed as an exception for almost every awk script ever posted. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or xpg6) instead of /usr/bin/awk or /bin/awk. Solaris also has nawk but it's less fully-featured and further from POSIX compliance then the xpg4/xpg6 awks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\([^,]*,\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\1\3-\2-01\4/' input_file
9999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,2021-01-01,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
```

Comment: The exit was different from yours. It is returning the date as follows: 
9999999,021-22-01,I,