# Keep every process in 1 execution block in CSV handling

Tags: bash, awk, sed, python, cat

I asked some questions about how to handle a csv file and this result was numerous processes.

Every month I get several TXT files in a Google Drive directory. I need to process, unite and load this information into a Postgres bank.

The received file has this layout and structure:

```
#A1401099999999              022021I                                   
00999999999   000000000099999999+000000000000000000-000000000000000000-   
00999999999   000000000099999999-000000000000000000-000000000000000000-  
00999999999   000000000099999999-000000000000000000-000000000000000000-
@036
```

I do a treatment where I split the file header into 3 columns using AWK:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    pfx = substr($0,8,7) OFS substr($0,30,6) OFS substr($0,36,1)
    next
}
{
    gsub(/[+-]/,"& ")
    $1 = pfx OFS $1
    print
}
```

The result

```
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
@036
```

In the next step I make the union of all files changed to this pattern:

```
cat -T *.txt > final.csv 


9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
@036
9999999,022021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,022021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,022021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,022021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-    
@042
```

I remove the baseboard :

```
sed -i '/@/d' final.csv

9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,012021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,022021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,022021,I,0099999999,000000000099999999-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,022021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
9999999,022021,S,0099999999,000000000099999999-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-
```

I edited field 2 formatting as date. It was 'MM/YYYY'. It is now 'yyyy-mm-01'. Where I put 01 as a default for dd.

```
awk -F, '{OFS=",";a=substr($2,1,2);b=substr($2,3,4);$2=b"-"a"-01";print $0}' final.csv
```

Result:

```
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,000000000009102629+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,000000000063288833+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,000000000063288833+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,000000000063288833+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,000000008017897139+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

Now to be able to use functions in column 5, I need to change the position from the "-" to the beginning of the column when the values ​​are negative

```
awk -F "," '{sign=substr($5,length($5),1);$5=substr($5,0,length($5)-1); if(sign =="-"){$5="-"$5}; print}' ./mycsv

    10013534,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,000000000009102629,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
    10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,-000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
    10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,-000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
    10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
    10013534,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,-000000008017897139,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

After all this treatment I want to import the data to Postgres

```
import pandas, csv

from io import StringIO
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
   dbapi_conn = conn.connection
   with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
       s_buf = StringIO()
       writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
       writer.writerows(data_iter)
       s_buf.seek(0)
       columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
       if table.schema:
           table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name, columns)
       else:
           table_name = table.name
       sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(table_name, columns)
       cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxxxx:xxx@xxxx:xxx/xxxx')

df = pandas.read_csv("final.csv")
df.to_sql('xxxxxxx', engine, schema='xxxxxxx', method=psql_insert_copy)
```

Comment: Keeping this in separate pieces (which are individually easy to change) has its advantages.

Comment: What's your question?   What are you stuck on or need help with?  You know what you want to do, you have awk prototypes for pre-processing the text input, and it seems python is your preferred programming language, and you already know good python libraries for working with both CSV and postgresql - so, just do it, convert the awk algorithms to python. There isn't anything awk can do that you can't also do in python.  They're both good general purpose programming languages, each with their own strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @cas 
Right now I want to move the "-" around. Putting him at the beginning of the field.

The idea is to ask for suggestions to be able to unite all the processes listed.

I got a suggestion to do the entire Pipeline in Apache Airflow