# Changing the place operator in a csv file

Tags: awk, sed, python, cat, dash

I've been editing a CSV file so I can import it into postgres. At this point I want to change the operator from column 5 to the left side of the column when the value is negative"-". When it is "+" I would like to delete the operator.

current CSV:

```
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,000000000009102629+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,000000000063288833-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,000000000063288833-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,000000000063288833+,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,000000008017897139-,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

**how should it look**

```
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,000000000009102629,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,-000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,-000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,-000000008017897139,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```

Column 6 and 7 can be deleted if necessary

Comment: you have asked several similar question but nothing you learned from the answers you received? would you please show your attempts and where do you have a problem resolving it? and you are still using some wrong tags for your questions like `cat`, `dash`

Comment: @αғsнιη 
I've described every process I'm putting together here. If you have time and want to read it.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683363/keep-every-process-in-1-execution-block-in-csv-handling

Comment: Again, why are you adding even more processing steps? It would be so much more efficient to do all of your tiny modifications on the _original_, data in one go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep every process in 1 execution block in CSV handling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683363/keep-every-process-in-1-execution-block-in-csv-handling)

Comment: @they I wanted to do this. But every time I put the steps together, the syntax gets wrong. So I'm going to do it separately and join the processes in Airflow

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/683363/keep-every-process-in-1-execution-block-in-csv-handling : I created this topic to join the processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
awk -F "," '{sign=substr($5,length($5),1);$5=substr($5,0,length($5)-1); if(sign =="-"){$5="-"$5}; print}' ./mycsv
```

Comment: the file has lost tab. The "," are gone from the file.

Comment: @matheus soares: You know how to set ```OFS```, don't you?

Comment: Understand. Thanks to your comment I was able to see where I was going wrong:

awk -F "," 'OFS=","{sign=substr($5,length($5),1);$5=substr($5,0,length($5)-1); if(sign =="-"){$5="-"$5}; print}' ./mycsv

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
function movesign (TMP) {IX  = sub (/\+$/, "&", TMP)       # create increment based on sign, so
                                                           # to drop the plus signs
                         return substr (TMP TMP, length(TMP) + IX, length(TMP) - IX)
                                                           # by writing the string twice, and chop-
                                                           # ping it off at the right position with
                                                           # the right length, we get the desired result
                        }                       

/^#/    {pfx = substr($0, 8, 7) OFS substr($0, 32, 4) "-" substr($0, 30, 2) "-01" OFS substr($0, 36) 
                                                           # prepare prefix from header lines
         sub (/ *$/, "", pfx)                              # trim trailing spaces
         next
        }
/^@/    {next
        }

        {gsub(/[+-]/, "&,")                                # massage the input line into the right shape
          sub(/[, ]*$/, "")
         gsub(/  */, ",")

         $1 = pfx OFS $1                                   # prepend the prefix
         $0 = $0                                           # and recalculate the fields

         $5 = movesign($5)                                 # use function to taste
#        $6 = movesign($6)
#        $7 = movesign($7)
        }
1
' OFS=, *.csv
```

It's stealing in the answers you got so far but does all steps in one go, on all `.csv` files in your `cwd`. See the comments for the logics, and come back should questions arise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure remains the same and column 5 is the first match after a comma with more than 10 integer characters, you can try this `sed` which will move the `-` dash if it is the character found or exclude the `+` if it is the character found.

```
$ sed 's/,\([0-9]\{10,\}[^,]*\)\(-\)\|+,/,\2\1/' input_file
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0090922002,000000000009102629,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091000002,-000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091100005,-000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0091110002,000000000063288833,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
10013534,2021-01-01,I,0099999995,-000000008017897139,000000000000000000-,000000000000000000-,
```